# reportviewer wait cursor positioning issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, report-viewer2010

I'm having an issue with msft report viewer wait cursor positioning.

It would appear that msft didn't add the ability to set the position (it must be a feature).

Does anybody know a work around?

Comment: Post your code to try to help you

Comment: Lucas the only code i have for this are property settings. I can post those if you would like to see them.